# How to mark as active when hover on image element (not empty [transparent] zone)

Tags: javascript, html, css

The image is quadrangle (you can see at border), i need mark as active element only when hover on image element, now he active when i move on empty white space near triangle and etc.

**My problem**: i need ignore transparency place

[image]

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0vc33e2n/

```
<img src='http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-transparent-glass-icons-media/001429-3d-transparent-glass-icon-media-a-media21-arrow-back.png' style='position: absolute; top: -50px; left: -70px'>
<img src='http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-transparent-glass-icons-transport-travel/036411-3d-transparent-glass-icon-transport-travel-anchor6-sc48.png' style='position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px'>
```

Comment: If I understand your issue, you only want the anchor part of your image to be clickable. You may want to look into [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) and [`<area>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap both images in a div and when the user hovers over the div, you set the value of the image you want, like so:

**HTML**

```
<div id="hoverArea"><img src='http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-transparent-glass-icons-media/001429-3d-transparent-glass-icon-media-a-media21-arrow-back.png' style='position: absolute; top: -50px; left: -70px'>
<img src='http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-transparent-glass-icons-transport-travel/036411-3d-transparent-glass-icon-transport-travel-anchor6-sc48.png' style='position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px' class="canHaveBlueBackground"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#hoverArea:hover .canHaveBlueBackground {
  background: blue;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0vc33e2n/3/